# MD5SUM on dIfferent server

Tags: linux, ssh, md5, md5sum

need help im use this script for MD5SUM

```
#export file different server
export FILES=`sshpass -p sys0ra ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no oracle@10.20.30.01 ls -th /dump/20171217`
export FILES2=`sshpass -p sys0ra ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no oracle@192.168.0.01 ls -th /dump2/20171217`

#the main for loop execution starts here. 
for entry in "$FILES"
do

    filename=$(basename "$entry")
    filename2=$(basename "$entry2")
    echo "File Name: $filename"
    echo "File Name: $filename2"

    #calculate md5sum    
    server1_md5sum=$(md5sum "$entry")
    echo "Server 1 MD5Sum: $server1_md5sum"
    server2_md5sum=$(md5sum "$FILES2")  
    echo "Server 2 Md5sum: $server2_md5sum"
    read -p "pause"
done
```

please help ...

i exec this query but md5sum cant look path export and export2

Comment: Where does `entry2` come from? See also [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `entry2` other server .

Comment: I get that, where in your script is it every assigned a value? Nowhere in the script you show is assignment ever made to `entry2`  (e.g. there is no `entry2=anything`). Your `entry` variable is the `for` loop variable assigned from your capture of the *command substitution* in FILES`. There is nothing similar done for `entry2`. Have you run your script through [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)??